# Faster method for partial fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

Is there a way to apply the "cover-up" method when solving for fractions of the following type?
$$\frac {2x}{(x+1)(x^2+1)^2}$$
The long way would be;
$$\frac {2x}{(x+1)(x^2+1)^2} = \frac {A}{x+1} +   \frac{Bx+C}{x^2+1} + \frac{Dx+E}{(x^2+1)^2}.$$
It's easy to get $A$, which is $A = \frac{-1}{2}$.  But for the rest, is there a fast trick?

Comment: You could try working with complex numbers.

Comment: that seems to complicate things, giving complex fractions.
Is there a way to return it back to real numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having obtained $A$, you can resort to complex numbers as Brad has suggested, as it will simplify things considerably by eliminating $A$,$B$ and $C$, and you will return to real numbers.
$$\frac {2x}{(x+1)(x^2+1)^2}=\frac {A}{x+1} +   \frac{Bx+C}{x^2+1} + \frac{Dx+E}{(x^2+1)^2}\\\Rightarrow 2x=A(x^2+1)^2+(Bx+C)(x+1)(x^2+1)+(Dx+E)(x+1) \color{blue}{\text{ Eq.(1)}}$$
Setting $x=i$ in Eq.($1$) will result in
$$2i=(Di+E)(i+1)=(E-D)+(E+D)i \color{blue}{\text{ Eq.(2)}}$$
Equating the real component ($0$) and the imaginary component ($2$) in Eq.($2$) results in $E=D=1$.

Having found $A,E,D$ set $x=0$ in Eq.($1$), so that you obtain
$$A+C+1=0\Rightarrow C=-1-A=-\frac{1}{2}$$
It remains to find $B$, which can be done by setting $x=1$ in Eq.(1) resulting in
$$4A+4(B+C)+2(D+E)=2\Rightarrow B=2-A-C-\frac{(D+E)}{4}=\frac{1}{2}$$
Thus the partial fraction decomposition is
$$\frac {2x}{(x+1)(x^2+1)^2}=-\frac {1}{2(x+1)} +   \frac{x-1}{2(x^2+1)} + \frac{x+1}{(x^2+1)^2}$$